# Trying to install packages individually?

Tags: package-management, upgrade, updates, source-packages

I tried updating in many ways but I've been running into the same display basically saying that 6 packages werent upgraded. (you can see the whole question in my profile) and after some troubleshooting i've began to try and install packages individually but i'm not quite the tech savvy yet but wanted to know if the command i used was correctly utilized.

```
dcg@dcg-IdeaPad-5-15ITL05:~$ sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install jammy-updates 12ubuntu4.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 12ubuntu4.1]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package jammy-updates
E: Unable to locate package 12ubuntu4.2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '12ubuntu4.2'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex '12ubuntu4.2'
E: Unable to locate package amd64
E: Unable to locate package [upgradable
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '[upgradable'
E: Regex compilation error - Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=
E: Couldn't find any package by regex '[upgradable'
E: Unable to locate package from:
E: Unable to locate package 12ubuntu4.1]
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '12ubuntu4.1]'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex '12ubuntu4.1]'
```

Can you let me know if it was correctly used? (i doubt it since it couldnt find any package...)

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Answer (score 1):

The only proper way to install packages needing updates are through `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade` because any packages which have new dependencies will get those new dependencies pulled in *and* updated.

There is no `jammy-updates` package nor any regex pattern match that'll be a specific version in the string.  Your message simply said there are 6 packages to update, not the packages you needed to update/upgrade.  `apt` has the inbuilt commands already to do the upgrade, you just have to instruct it to like I specified above.

Comment: I see. Given that I've tried multiple options including the normal sudo apt update/upgrade and even full upgrade I can't figure out what's wrong...If you check my question "Update/Upgrade not working" you can check the rest of the procedures I tried. Can you hint me at what is causing this stubborn problem?

Comment: @DavidGraça then this question is a duplicate of your original question.  **DO NOT** create multiple questions for the same exact issue.  Stick to one question.

Comment: Understood! Won't happen again, thanks